# Weird behavior of flipflop.in

Tags: circuitikz

Why i get these weird line on input of flipflop

[image: hereIam]

and there is how it should be
[image: main goal]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikz}
    \draw 
    (2,-.5) to[short] (2,-10)
    (0,0) to[short, -*] (1,0)
    (4,0) node[label,and port/] (myand1) {1}
    (1,-1) node[label,american not port,rotate=270] (prvone)    

    (1,0) -| (myand1.in 1)
    (2,-.5) -| (myand1.in 2)
    (1,0) -| (prvone.in)

     %node [american not port,rotate=270] (5,-3)    
    ;
\end{tikz}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Please post a compilable example so that we can help you...

Comment: That is what I have

Comment: nodes are normally positioned by their centers, but you can specify any anchor.

Comment: @amygdala27 no, your snippet does not compile. It is completely missing the preamble and the needed packages. Please take a moment to read what a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is...

Answer (score 1):

Is this more like what you want?

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw 
    (0,0) to[short, -*] (1,0) -- (2,0) node[and port, anchor=in 1] (myand1) {1}
    (1,-1) node[american not port,rotate=-90] (prvone) {}
    (myand1.in 2) -| (2,-4)
    (1,0) -| (prvone.in)
    (myand1.south) node[and port, below=\baselineskip] (myand2) {2}% 0 would be touching
    %(myand2.in 1) to[short,-*] (2,0 |- myand2.in 1)
    (myand2.in 1) node[circ]{}% since they are already touching
    (prvone.out) |- (myand2.in 2)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: btw how can I edit hegiht and width of these

Comment: `\ctikzset{tripoles/american and port/height=.8}` and `\ctikzset{tripoles/american and port/width=1.1}` (default, relative to normal bipole height and width).

Comment: Actually, you probably want ieee logic ports.

Comment: John Kormylo like these on photo