# Drawing logical schema using circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, logic

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw 
    (0,0) to[short, -*] (1,0) -- (2,0) node[and port, anchor=in 1] (myand1) {}
    (1,-1) node[american not port,rotate=-90] (prvone) {}
    (myand1.in 2) -| (2,-4)
    (1,0) -| (prvone.in)
    (myand1.south) node[and port, below=\baselineskip] (myand2) {}
    (myand2.in 1) node[circ]{}
    (prvone.out) |- (myand2.in 2)
    ;
    \node[
        dipchip,
        num pins=6,
        hide numbers,
        no topmark,
        external pins width=0](ff1) at (3.5,0)      {};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 1) {\textsl{S}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 2) {\textsl{CP}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 3) {\textsl{R}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 6) {\textsl{Q}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 4) {\textsl{\ctikztextnot{Q}}};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Register]

I am beginner in LaTex. Any help, books or manuals how to use circuitikz to get schemas like this one.I've read manual on CTAN but it wasn't very helpful.Not sure how to connect the custom elements.
Thank you in advance.

[image: How to connect the parts]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543404/weird-behavior-of-flipflop-in/543456#543456

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529674/circuitikz-logic-gates

Comment: I  added the code.It's required in assignment to include logic US circuit but it doesn't work when I do that.

Comment: @Nina77 IEEE standard ports are very recent, look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic principle is the same as myand1.  You use the anchor keyword to locate what part of the component you wish to align.  In this case, I located (ff1.pin 1) to the right of (myand1.out), then located (myand2.out) to the left of (ff1.pin 3).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw 
    (0,0) to[short, -*] (1,0) -- (2,0) node[and port, anchor=in 1] (myand1) {}
    (1,-1) node[american not port,rotate=-90] (prvone) {}
    (myand1.in 2) -| (2,-4)
    (1,0) -| (prvone.in)
    ;
    \ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing=0.5}% increasee size of dipchip
    \draw (myand1.out) -- ++(1,0) node[anchor=pin 1,
        dipchip,
        num pins=6,
        hide numbers,
        no topmark,
        external pins width=0](ff1) {}
    (ff1.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[and port, anchor=out] (myand2) {}
    (myand2.in 1) node[circ]{}
    (prvone.out) |- (myand2.in 2);

    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 1) {\textsl{S}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 2) {\textsl{CP}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 3) {\textsl{R}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 6) {\textsl{Q}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 4) {\textsl{\ctikztextnot{Q}}};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've started drawing the same one but how can I connect these two flipflops into one shematics?

Comment: You draw another flipflop just like the first but in a different location (and with different names).