# Logical schema and flip flops using circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, errors, diagrams, circuitikz

I'm a beginner in LaTeX, and I have a problem to finish this schema.

[image: This is how it should look like.]

And I made the following:

[image: now]

I don't know where the problem is and I don't have any books to consult for this. Please, help me!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} [circuit logic US, every circuit symbol/.style={scale=0.65}]
    \draw 
    (0,0) to[short, -*] (1,0) -- (2,0) node[and port, anchor=in 1] (myand1) {}
    (1,-1) node[american not port,rotate=-90] (prvone) {}
    (myand1.in 2) -| (2,-4)
    (1,0) -| (prvone.in)
    ;
    \ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing=0.5}
    \draw (myand1.out) -- ++(1,0) node[anchor=pin 1,
        dipchip,
        num pins=6,
        hide numbers,
        no topmark,
        external pins width=0](ff1) {}
    (ff1.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[and port, anchor=out] (myand2) {}
    (myand2.in 1) node[circ]{}
    (prvone.out) |- (myand2.in 2);

    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 1) {\textsl{S}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 2) {\textsl{CP}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 3) {\textsl{R}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 6) {\textsl{Q}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 4) {\textsl{\ctikztextnot{Q}}};

     \draw 
    (0,5) to[short, -*] (1,5) -- (2,5) node[and port, anchor=in 1] (myand1) {}
    (1,-1) node[american not port,rotate=-90] (prvone) {}
    (myand1.in 2) -| (2,-4)
    (0,5) -| (prvone.in)
    ;
    \ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing=0.5}
    \draw (myand1.out) -- ++(1,0) node[anchor=pin 1,
        dipchip,
        num pins=6,
        hide numbers,
        no topmark,
        external pins width=0](ff1) {}
    (ff1.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[and port, anchor=out] (myand2) {}
    (myand2.in 1) node[circ]{}
    (prvone.out) |- (myand2.in 2);

    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 1) {\textsl{S}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 2) {\textsl{CP}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 3) {\textsl{R}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 6) {\textsl{Q}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 4) {\textsl{\ctikztextnot{Q}}};
    

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Among other errors, you are mixing the TikZ circuit library and `circuitikz` (in an incorrect way). You have the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) and the [CircuiTikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) available... I have notime now but I'll try to give it a spin later.

Comment: Anyway, this is again the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544207/drawing-logical-schema-using-circuitikz ... fourth time... what's happening here?

Comment: @Rmano do you want to close the others in favour of this one (or we could close this as dup but then you should probably move your answer to the unclosed one...)

Comment: I can move my answer... I suppose it's just copy and paste?

Comment: @userxxx, is any answer solving your problem? Please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and try to be nice with people that tried to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Ok. Sit down because this will be long --- let's see if I can do a tutorial. You have to have done the Ti*k*Z tutorial to fully understand this, especially the `calc` package and the `|-` coordinate operator.

Looking at the circuit to draw, I see that there is a basic block: the flip-flop with the added three-port circuit to the left. The main distance to respect here is that we want the two ANDs in line with the inputs, so I'll start with the flip-flop and then do the rest. I want a reusable block, so I start from a coordinate and then go relative, defining coordinates along the way. The standard size of the port is a bit too big with respect to the flip-flop, so I scale them down a bit.

Follow the comments in the code:

```latex
 \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\tikzset{sr-ff/.style={flipflop, flipflop def={
    t1=S, t2=CP, t3=R, t4={\ctikztextnot{Q}},t6=Q, nd=1}},
}
\ctikzset{
        logic ports/scale=0.7,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[sr-ff](FF){} (FF.up) node[above]{SR-FF}
        (FF.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[and port, anchor=out](AND1){}
        % notice the second coordinate here, so that I have just one number 
        % to change if I want more or less space
        (FF.pin 3) -- (FF.pin 3 -| AND1.out) node[and port, anchor=out](AND2){}
        % go left again to put the not insert point
        (AND1.in 1) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(not up)
        % let's position the NOT in the center to be really finicky
        % this is using the calc tikz library
        ($(not up)!0.5!(not up|- AND2.in 2)$) node[not port, rotate=-90](NOT){}
        % and connect it
        (not up) -- (NOT.in) (NOT.out) |- (AND2.in 2)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

And this gives me:

[image]

Ok, now I want to reuse the block --- I will put the code into a `\newcommand` and use two of them.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
% see the circuitikz manual at flip-flops
\tikzset{sr-ff/.style={flipflop, flipflop def={
    t1=S, t2=CP, t3=R, t4={\ctikztextnot{Q}},t6=Q, nd=1}},
}
\ctikzset{
        logic ports/scale=0.7,
}
\newcommand{\myblock}[1]{% the parameter will be prepended to the relevant node names
    node[sr-ff](#1-FF){} (#1-FF.up) node[above]{SR-FF}
        (#1-FF.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[and port, anchor=out](#1-AND1){}
        % notice the second coordinate here, so that I have just one number
        % to change if I want more or less space
        (#1-FF.pin 3) -- (#1-FF.pin 3 -| #1-AND1.out) node[and port, anchor=out](#1-AND2){}
        % go left again to put the not insert point
        (#1-AND1.in 1) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(not up)
        % let's position the NOT in the center to be really finicky
        % this is using the calc tikz library
        ($(not up)!0.5!(not up|- #1-AND2.in 2)$) node[not port, rotate=-90](#1-NOT){}
        % and connect it
        (not up) -- (#1-NOT.in) (#1-NOT.out) |- (#1-AND2.in 2)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) \myblock{A};
    \draw (0,-5) \myblock{B};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...and now you just add the connections between your nice blocks (whose anchors are prepended by `A-` and `B-`:

```latex
    \draw (A-AND1.in 2) to[short, -*] (A-AND2.in 1)
        to[short, -*] (B-AND1.in 2) to[short, -*] (B-AND2.in 1)
        -- ++(0, -2) coordinate(down) node[below]{ENABLE};
    \draw (A-FF.pin 2) to[short, -*] (B-FF.pin 2)
        -- (B-FF.pin 2 |- down) node[below]{CP};
    % look at the manual again here
    \draw (B-FF-Nd.south) to[short, -*] ++(0,-0.3) coordinate(dd);
    \draw (A-FF-Nd.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(2,0) |- (dd)
        -- (dd |- down) node[below]{RESET};
    \draw (A-in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) node[below]{$a_0$};
    \draw (B-in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) node[below]{$a_1$};
```

to have:

[image]

Comment: ah u beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

A partial attempt

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikzgit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, backgrounds, calc, positioning, circuits.logic.US, circuits, 
arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC}

\tikzset{flipflop AB/.style={flipflop,flipflop def={t1=S, t3=R, t6=Q, t4= 
{\ctikztextnot{Q}}, td=rst, nd=1, c2=1, n2=1, t2={\texttt{CP}}}}}
\ctikzset{logic ports/scale=0.6} %page 107 circuitikz manual


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]

    %position flip flop
    \node[flipflop AB](ff1) at (0,0){};
    \node[flipflop AB](ff2) at (0,-4){};

    %drawing path
    \path[draw](ff1.down)--++(2,0)|-(ff2.down);
    \draw[blue](ff2.down) node[circ, color=blue](rst2){}--++(0,-0.5){};

    \path[draw](ff1-N2.west)--++(-0.5,0)|-(ff2-N2.west);
    \draw[blue](ff2-N2.west)--++(-0.5,0) node[circ, color=blue](N2){}{}--++(0,-2.05);

    %labeling
    \node [below=4mm of ff2.down,font=\tiny](reset)  {RESET};
    \node [left=6mm of reset,font=\tiny](cp)  {CP};
    \node [left=9mm of cp,font=\tiny](enable)  {ENABLE};

    %position gate
    \draw(ff1.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[american and port](and1){};
    \draw(ff2.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[american and port](and2){};
    \draw(ff1.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[american and port](and3){};
    \draw(ff2.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[american and port](and4){};
    \draw(and3.in 2) -- ++(-1,0) node(x){} |-(and1.in 1);
    \draw(and4.in 2) -- ++(-1,0) node(x){} |-(and2.in 1);
    \draw(and1.in 2) -- ++(-0.25,0) node(w){} --(enable);


    \draw(and2.in 2) -- ++(-0.25,0) node[circ,color=green](e1){} ;
    \draw(and3.in 1) -- ++(-0.25,0) node[circ,color=green](e1){} ;
    \draw(and4.in 1) -- ++(-0.25,0) node[circ,color=green](e1){} ;
    \draw(and2.in 2) -- ++(-0.25,0) node[circ,color=green](e1){} ;

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

**EDIT__ Completion-- copied over the 0.5 placement for the `not port` from the solution by @Rmano**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikzgit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, backgrounds, calc, positioning, circuits.logic.US, circuits, arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC}

\tikzset{flipflop AB/.style={flipflop,flipflop def={t1=S, t3=R, t6=Q, t4={\ctikztextnot{Q}}, td=rst, nd=1, c2=1, n2=1, t2={\texttt{CP}}}}}
\ctikzset{logic ports/scale=0.6} %page 107 circuitikz manual


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
    %position flip flop
    \node[flipflop AB](ff1) at (0,0){};
    \node[flipflop AB](ff2) at (0,-4){};

    %drawing path
    \path[draw](ff1.down)--++(2,0)|-(ff2.down);

    \path[draw](ff1-N2.west)--++(-0.5,0)|-(ff2-N2.west);


    %labeling
    \node [below=4mm of ff2.down,font=\tiny](reset)  {RESET};
    \node [left=6.2mm of reset,font=\tiny](cp)  {CP};
    \node [left=8.8mm of cp,font=\tiny](enable)  {ENABLE};


    %position gate
    \draw(ff1.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[american and port](and1){};
    \draw(ff2.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[american and port](and2){};
    \draw(ff1.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[american and port](and3){};
    \draw(ff2.pin 3) -- ++(-1,0) node[american and port](and4){};

    \draw(and1.in 2) -- ++(-0.25,0) node(w){} --(enable);
    \draw[blue](ff2.down) node[circ, color=blue](rst2){}--(reset);
    \draw[blue](ff2-N2.west)--++(-0.5,0) node[circ, color=blue](N2){}--(cp);

    %draw nodes
    \draw(and2.in 2) -- ++(-0.25,0) node[circ,color=green](e1){} ;
    \draw(and3.in 1) -- ++(-0.25,0) node[circ,color=green](e1){} ;
    \draw(and4.in 1) -- ++(-0.25,0) node[circ,color=green](e1){} ;
    \draw(and2.in 2) -- ++(-0.25,0) node[circ,color=green](e1){} ;

    %not port1    
    \draw 
    (and1.in 1) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(q)
    ($(q)!0.5!(q|- and3.in 2)$) node[not port, point down](not1){}
    (q) -- (not1.in) (not1.out) |- (and3.in 2)
    (q) --++(-4mm,0)
    ;

    %not port2    
    \draw 
    (and2.in 1) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(q1)
    ($(q1)!0.5!(q1|- and4.in 2)$) node[not port, point down](not2){}
    (q1) -- (not2.in) (not2.out) |- (and4.in 2)
    (q1) --++(-4mm,0)
    ;

    %labeling
        \node [left=2.5mm of q,font=\tiny](a0)  {$a_1$};    
        \node [left=2.5mm of q1,font=\tiny](a0)  {$a_0$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```