# Add ports for flipflop in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

I've got this so far:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\node[flipflop D] (D) at (2,0) {};
\node[flipflop T] (T) at (6,0) {};
\node[flipflop JK] (JK) at (10,0) {};

\draw[SkyBlue] (D.pin 4) -| (3.8,0) |- (T.pin 1);
\draw[SkyBlue] (T.pin 6) -- (JK.pin 1);
\draw[OliveGreen] (D.pin 6) -| (3.5,-1.5) -| (JK.pin 3);

\draw (JK.pin 6) -- ++(1, 0)node[right] {$Q_4$};
\draw (D.pin 1) -- ++(-1, 0)node[left] {D};

\draw (0,-2) node[left] {$clock$} -- (0.5,-2) node[circ] (clk1) {};
\draw (clk1) -- (4,-2) node[circ] (clk2) {};
\draw (clk2) -- (8,-2) |- (JK.pin 2);
\draw (clk1) |- (D.pin 3);
\draw (clk2) |- (T.pin 3);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

How do I add the preset and clear?

ETA: Figured it out:

```
    \draw (0,-3) node[left] {$clear$} -| (D.bdown)node[ocirc,below]{};
\draw (0,2) node[left] {$preset$} -| (D.bup)node[ocirc,above]{};
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545506/263192 help?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

You may define a custom flip-flop with preset and clear.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

%---------------------------------------------------
\tikzset{flipflop DMod/.style={flipflop,
    flipflop def={t1=D, t6=Q, t4={\ctikztextnot{Q}},
        tu=pre, nu=1, td=clr, nd=1, c3=1},
}} 
%---------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\node[flipflop DMod] (D) at (2,0) {};
\node[flipflop T] (T) at (6,0) {};
\node[flipflop JK] (JK) at (10,0) {};

\draw (D.pin 4) -| (3.8,0) |- (T.pin 1);
\draw (T.pin 6) -- (JK.pin 1);
\draw (D.pin 6) -| (3.5,-1.5) -| (JK.pin 3);

\draw (JK.pin 6) -- ++(1, 0)node[right] {$Q_4$};
\draw (D.pin 1) -- ++(-1, 0)node[left] {D};

\draw (0,-2) node[left] {$clock$} -- (0.5,-2) node[circ] (clk1) {};
\draw (clk1) -- (4,-2) node[circ] (clk2) {};
\draw (clk2) -- (8,-2) |- (JK.pin 2);
\draw (clk1) |- (D.pin 3);
\draw (clk2) |- (T.pin 3);

\draw (D.up) |- ++(-2, 0)node[left] {preset}; %--> added
\draw (D.down) |- ++(-2, 0)node[left] {clear}; %--> added
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To add to @Imran's excellent answer, I just want to point out that section 3.25 of the manual on page 127 describes what all those nu, td, nd, etc are.  2 pages later, in section 3.25.1, there is a very good example.  (Valid for version 1.3.0 of the manual)